# How to get each title attribute into value of input tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to grab each title attribute into value of input tag but i tried so many way, but all of it's fail, i even try to loop using for().

For example **this is my code before add javascript**

```
<div class="all">
  <div class="myOtherClass">
    <a class="getTitle test" href="#" Title="i want grab this title">click me to change</a>
  </div>
  <div class="myOtherClass">
    <a class="getTitle test" href="#" Title="i want grab this too">click me to change</a>
  </div>
  <div class="myOtherClass">
    <a class="getTitle test" href="#" Title="same at 2 other">click me to change</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Otherclass">
    <input class="myInput" type="button" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**This is what i'm tried to do**

```
let getTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.getTitle').forEach((f) => {
    f.addEventListener('click', function() {
     document.querySelectorAll('.all').forEach(item =>{

      let button = item.querySelector('.getinput')          
      let a = item.querySelectorAll('.test');
       for(let i=0; i < a.length; i++){
          let atitle = a[i];
          button.value = atitle.title; 
        }
       })
      })
     })
```

---

**This is what i want my codes do after add javascript**

> when i click on the first a tag is will return the value in input is

```
<input class="myInput" type="button" value="i want grab this title"/>
```

---

> And when i click the second a tag will return this value

```
<input class="myInput" type="button" value="i want grab this too"/>
```

---

**but the result i made just like this**

> when i click on the first a tag is return the value in input is

```
<input class="myInput" type="button" value="i want grab this title"/>
```

---

> And when i click the second a tag is return the same value of the first a tag

```
<input class="myInput" type="button" value="i want grab this title"/>
```

Is there a way to solve this solution ??

Comment: what did you try in js?

Comment: "i tried so many way, but all of it's fail, i even try to loop using for() and it's just keep return 1 result." — We can't tell you where you went wrong without a [mcve]

Comment: @NyattoNguyễn — Large chucks of code in comments are unreadable. Put a [mcve] in the question itself. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: sorry i'm not used to it, i'm just new here

Comment: this is unclear, show us how the solution should be. and why is it a event listener ?

Comment: This feels like you want to create your own radio button implementation. Have you considered to just use html form radio buttons? Or a select-element?

Comment: there is no element with `class="getinput"` or `class="test"`

Comment: i'm doing a modal box and this its just my example code, here is my real code https://hastebin.com/yutuqexere.xml . I have to use example code because my code it's to long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event listeners on each of the anchor tags, and set the value of the input by **ID**, which you will need to change accordingly:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('getTitle')
const input = document.getElementById('[change_this]')
Array.from(elements).forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
    input.value = el.target.title
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="myOtherClass">
    <a class="getTitle test" Title="i want grab this title">click me to change</a>
  </div>
  <div class="myOtherClass">
    <a class="getTitle test" Title="i want grab this too">click me to change</a>
  </div>
  <div class="myOtherClass">
    <a class="getTitle test" Title="same at 2 other">click me to change</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Otherclass">
    <input id="[change_this]" class="myInput" type="button" value="" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what can be intelligible to what you do :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.getTitle').forEach( Z_elm => {
  Z_elm.addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.myInput').value = this.title;

    // or : (in your real code)
    // document.querySelector('#myModal .getinput').value = this.title;
  })
})
```

```css
a {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="myOtherClass">
    <a class="getTitle" Title="i want grab this title">click me to change</a>
  </div>
  <div class="myOtherClass">
    <a class="getTitle" Title="i want grab this too">click me to change</a>
  </div>
  <div class="myOtherClass">
    <a class="getTitle" Title="same at 2 other">click me to change</a>
  </div>
  <div class="Otherclass">
    <input class="myInput" type="button" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```